# Flutter not able connect to websocket

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

When I try to connect to my nodejs server it is showing me this error-

```json
connect_error: [{"cause":{"detailMessage":"Control frames must be final.","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

I used flutter_socket_io for socket connection

My flutter code

```
socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(
        websocketUrl, '/', socketStatusCallback: (status) {
          print("web socket -------------status");
          print(status);
      if (status.toString() == "connect") {
        print("connected to server with websocket------------------------");
        // socketIO.sendMessage("socket request", jsonEncode({"id": id}));
      }
    });

socketIO.init();
socketIO.connect().then((value){
  print('socket connect');
});
```

Comment: If it is possible, try to use dart native `dart:Io` package. which is more robust

Comment: the server work with http protocol, not ws or wss and WebSocket from dart.io work only with ws or wss so cannot use that here